# awk save command ouput to variable

Tags: linux, scripting, awk

I need to execute a command per line of some file. For example:

```
file1.txt 100 4
file2.txt 19 8
```

So my `awk` script need to execute something like

```
command $1 $2 $3
```

and save the output of `command $1 $2 $3`, so `system()` will not work and neither will `getline`. (I can't pipe the output if I do something like this.)

The restriction to this problem is to use only `awk`. (i already had a solution with bashscriot + awk...but I only want awk...just to know more about this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with using `getline`?

```
$ ./test.awk test.txt
# ls -F | grep test
test.awk*
test.txt

# cat test.txt | nl
     1  ls -F | grep test
     2  cat test.txt | nl
     3  cat test.awk

# cat test.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
        cmd[NR] = $0
        while ($0 | getline line) output[NR] = output[NR] line RS
}
END {
        for (i in cmd) print "# " cmd[i] ORS output[i]
}
```

Comment: this is bash script. when I use getline I cant pipe the command, for example
cat file | process parameters, I only gets the cat file.
I am doing this for more clean ways to do this task...

Comment: the last 10 lines answered my question

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was obvious that this was a demonstration of the script running on itself, but maybe it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Awk's system() function passes the string to /bin/sh, so you can use redirect operators, like ">file.out" if you want.

```
awk '{system("command " $1 " " $2 " " $3 ">" $1 ".out");}'
```

Edit: ok, by save, you mean into an awk variable.  ephemient is on the right track, then.  That's what awk's getline does, like backticks or $(cmd) in shell/perl.  In fact, google for awk backticks found this:
http://www.omnigroup.com/mailman/archive/macosx-admin/2006-May/054665.html

You say you can't use getline because then you couldn't pipe.  But you can work around that with tee and file-descriptor tricks.  This works if /bin/sh is bash:

```
{ "set +o posix; command " $1 " " $2 " "  $3  " | tee >(grep foo)"  | getline var; print toupper(var); } # bash-only, and broken.
```

`set +o posix` is necessary because awk runs bash as `sh`, which makes it go into posix mode after readings its startup files.  Hmm, I'm not having any luck getting that to work, and it requires bash anyway.

Ok, this works:

```
    $ touch foo bar
    $ echo "foo bar" | 
      awk '{ "{ ls " $1 " " $2 " "  $3  " | tee /dev/fd/10 | grep foo > /dev/tty; } 10>&1"  | getline var; print toupper(var); }'
    foo
    BAR
```

Comment: my actual solution is doing this, but I cant send the output of command to a variable

Comment: You could slurp the output back in with a subsequent `readline [...] < $1 ".out"` loop.  Don't forget to clean up after yourself...

Comment: I used some file-descriptor redirection to pipe and getline at the same time.  Does that do what you need?